# Spivak Calculus Chapter 8 Problem 10

Tags: real-analysis

10) Suppose $\alpha > 0$. Prove that every number $x$ can be written uniquely in the form 
$$x = k\cdot\alpha + x',$$
 where $k$ is an integer, and $0 \le x' < \alpha$.

Note: $x'$ denotes the derivative of $x$.

This question deals with least upper bounds, but after trying to solve this problem for 30 minutes, I am not sure how to start this proof. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: No! $x'$ is just another number lies between $0$ and $\alpha$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x'$ is not the derivative of $x$. It is just a real number. Take $k$ to be the largest integer less than or equal to $\frac x {\alpha}$ (i.e. the least upper bound of the set of integers that are less than or equal to $\frac x {\alpha}$)  and $x'=x-k\alpha$. Verify that $0\leq x' <\alpha$.

Comment: How would I prove this using the properties of least upper bounds?

Comment: So, can you show me each step of your proof so that I get an idea of how to do it?